# Given an array of lengths, find closest combination to a total length

Tags: python

I have two sets of variables, a static array of segment lengths and a dynamic final total length to be specified by the user.

For example, array `lengths = [50,40,80,30,108,25]`, `total = 150`.

How would I go about calculating the optimal combination of the lengths array values to get as close as possible to the specified total number?  Using only addition. As we are using segments with a specified length to get as close as possible to a target length.

Not all array values have to be used. Each array element can be used an unlimited amount of times, but we want to get to the final result using the least amount of math as possible (i.e. *do not want to do* **25+25**, instead of just using the 50)

Comment: The issue for me is, that while it seems like a simple question, I cannot even figure out how I would begin. because the more I think about it, the more complex it gets. Or maybe thats just me

Comment: Can we use all mathematical operators like +, -, *, / in the combination? or just +?

Comment: For my circumstance I can only use addition @brandon - updated original Question with this just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force way using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
def get_comb(A, N):
    out = []
    for i in range(1, N//min(A)):
        for j in combinations_with_replacement(A, i):
            out.append((list(j), abs(sum(j) - N)))
    return min(out, key=lambda x: (x[1], len(x[0])))[0]
```

Explanations: first store all the combinations and their absolute difference from the desired sum. Then take the min based on tuple value where 1st element is the difference computed above and the 2nd element is the length of the combination. This way it will prioritize min difference and when differences are same it will take the one with less elements.

Application:

```
In [15]: get_comb(a, 50)
Out[15]: [50]

In [16]: get_comb(a, 100)
Out[16]: [50, 50]

In [22]: get_comb(a, 60)
Out[22]: [30, 30]


In [24]: get_comb(a, 730)
Out[24]: [80, 80, 30, 108, 108, 108, 108, 108]

In [25]: get_comb(a, 73)
Out[25]: [50, 25]
```

Comment: This could work, but it doesn't have the ability to re-use the same number multiple times in the array. If I gave it an array with the choice between using two 20's or one 40, would it choose the 40? if so, I may be able to use this with some editing.

Comment: It will choose one 40 rather than two 20's. But here is a catch, if you have [80, 20] and [50, 50] for 100, it may choose the one that comes first in your input array

Comment: @user5505559 it uses `combinations_with_replacement`, which allows duplicates to be repeated any number of times.

Comment: By the way, to make this fully correct you need to go beyond `len(A)+1` - all the way up to `N // min(A)` in the worst case.

Comment: The first time I tried this code it was combination(A,i), it is updated now I see.

Comment: Yes, N//min(A) will do the trick for any N. But as said in other answers, it'd be intractable for large list

Comment: With get_comb(a,730), it could use +50,+25 to get to 723, rather than stopping at 648 (6*108),

Comment: because I was using range until len(A)+1, for completeness use N//min(A) suggested by kaya3

Comment: it it were to be used with floats instead of ints, N//min(a) would not work, how would you go about making it compatible with floats?

Comment: `from math import floor; N//min(floor(A))` should work for floats

Comment: Thanks a heap for the help, I also tried int(N//min(A)) which seems to have worked, was going to edit my question but you've already replied. :)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is NP-hard because an NP-complete variation of the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) can be reduced to it. The variation is that elements of the set can be used more than once. It can also be viewed as a variation of the [change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem); see [this question on cstheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8970/complexity-of-a-subset-sum-variant) for details.

If there is a combination with a sum exactly equalling the total, then that is the optimal solution so your algorithm would find it. Inversely, if there is no such combination, your algorithm would find a solution with a different sum; the fact that that different combination is optimal would prove that no subset exactly equals the sum.

So, since your problem is NP-hard, that means there is no known algorithm which gives exact answers and also scales efficiently to large inputs. If you need an algorithm which finds truly optimal solutions, then you won't do much better than some kind of [backtracking search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_search). Otherwise, if "good enough" is good enough, it is worth reading about [heuristic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm) for the subset sum problem, which can likely be adapted to your problem in a straightforward way.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations, you got yourself a [NP problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard)!

That's a kind of problem that doesn't have a deterministic solution to it yet. All we have are AI that don't necessarily return the best solution. Algorithms like [Genetic Algorithms](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-genetic-algorithms-including-example-code-e396e98d8bf3) or [Particle Swarm Optimization](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/particle-swarm-optimization) do a very great job at finding a good enough answer, just depends on how much time and processing power you're willing to use.

The one way you can surely get your optimal answer is, obviously, checking all possible combinations by brute force, but understand that as your array lengths grow in number of elements, the more options you have to combine them into having a value close enough to your input. This does not grow polynomially, that's why it is a different category of problem.

NP problems are the kind that most time it's easy enough to check if a solution is valid, but very hard and time consuming to find a better answer, since you have to check all other possible combinations.

I have developed the algorithms I described before and others to this finality, but I do sincerely recommend that you research a little more about this topic and see how big this can actually get.